# how to find summation of all elements of array c++

Tags: c++, arrays

I'm new to c++ but long story short ,  i want to write a c++ program that will accept input from user through an array and it will sum each array element input

```
 #include <iostream>
    #include <string>
    #include <math.h>
    using namespace std;
    int main() {
        int array[100];
        int sum;
    for(int i=0; i<100; i++){
      cout<<"Insert element "<<i<<": ";
      cin>>array[i];
      sum = array[i]+ //summ with the next array input;
cout<<sum;
      }
      return 0;
    }
```

means that if i enter any integer the program should be able to give the summation of the inputs in sequence  from the first input to the last input

Comment: `int sum = 0;` and `sum += array[i];` should work fine. Also you probably want to output `sum` only once, after the loop.

Comment: @willy Are you going to input 100 values?:)

Comment: @willy You need to initialize the variable sum: int sum = 0; And this output cout<<sum; should be placed after the compound statement of the for loop.

Comment: You don't need an array to sum 100 input numbers; you need an accumulator initialized to zero and *one* variable you (a) read, and (b) add to your accumulator, then repeat 99 more times.

Comment: @Vlad from Moscow
 yes bro but every when i enter a number the program must give me a sum of the entered number with previous entered number

Comment: Are you looking for [std::accumulate](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/accumulate)?

Answer (score 2):

C++ standard library already has a function to do this which is [`std::accumulate`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/accumulate):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <numeric>

int main() {
    int array[5] = {1,2,3,4,5};
    int total = std::accumulate(std::begin(array), std::end(array), 0);
    return 0;
}
```

If you plan to use not a full array you should use `std::begin(array)`, `std::begin(array) + amount` as ranges.

Comment: You should use a `std::array` for a fixed size (which user input certainly isn't) or `std::vector` for dynamic size.

Answer (score 1):

**initialize your sum var to 0 initially** and **write sum+=array[i]** instead of what you have written, there is also a limitation in this program as **value of sum after all user input should be <=10^9** as int datatype store no. approximately upto 10^9 so take note of this fact also. Write **cout<<sum<<endl;** instead to be able to distinguish till previous input sum to the new input sum.
Hope this will help.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a do while loop:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
#include<math.h>

int main()
{
    int array[100];
    int sum=0;
    int i=0;
    std::cout<<"Insert element"<<" "<<i<<": ";
    std::cin>>array[i];
    do
    { 
        sum=sum+array[i];
        std::cout<<sum<<std::endl;
        i++;
        std::cout<<"Insert element"<<" "<<i<<": ";
    }while(std::cin>>array[i]);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: This will fail if I want the sum of 0 elements since the first input isn't checked.

Answer (score 1):

If all you want is the sum then just compute the sum. No need to store anything:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <math.h>

int main() {
    int sum = 0;
    for(int i=0; i<100; i++){
        std::cout << "Insert element " << i << ": ";
        int t;
        std::cin >> t;
        sum += t
        std::cout << sum;
    }
}
```